# How to prove $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}_k^n) = 0$ when $k$ is an algebraic closed field of char 0?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fundamental-groups

I know that to prove $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}_k^n) = 0$, one can just use the curve case and proceed by induction. For example, if $n=2$ and there is any connected etale covering, one can choose any line in $\mathbb{P}_k^2$. The inverse image of the line is the support of an ample divisor hence connected by Hartshorne III.7.9. Then one can conclude the covering is of degree 1 and finish the proof.
But I don’t know how to do this in the affine case and I don’t want to use comparison theorem to the topological fundamental group. Can someone tell me how to do this? Thank you very much!

I’m not sure if the following argument works. One can prove that if $k$ is not required to be algebraic closed, then all connected finite etale coverings of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ are $\mathbb{A}_{k’}^n$ where $k’/k$ is a finite separable extension. Now we can do induction as following. When $k$ is algebraic closed, If $f:X\rightarrow Spec(k[x,y])$is a connected finite etale covering, then so is the base change$f’:X’\rightarrow Spec(k(x)[y])$. By induction hypothesis, $X’=Spec(L[y])$ where $L$ is a finite separable extension of $k(x)$. Hence the generic fiber of $y=0$ is $Spec(L)$ which is connected. Then one can use induction hypothesis to conclude $X=\mathbb{A}_k^n$. When k is not algebraic closed, I guess it can be deduced from the precious case.

Comment: I gave an answer for $\mathbb{A}^1$ using Riemann-Hurwitz before noticing you asked for $\mathbb{A}^n$, sorry!

Comment: I'm not sure I know a proof that doesn't use the theory over $\mathbb{C}$ at some point. In particular, the most cop-out answers is that in characteristic $0$ the etale fundamental group commutes with products. But, of course, the only proof I know of this reduces to $\mathbb{C}$ (which is highly non-trivial since you still need that for non-proper things in characteristic $0$ the etale fundamental group is invariant under base field extension--see this https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.09690.pdf for an algebraic proof). Do you expect such a proof to be possible? Questions of purely algebraic

Comment: computations of the fundamental group are quite deep. For instance, you might find this paper interesting: https://math.berkeley.edu/~molsson/stump2.4.pdf. Of course, maybe there's some very tricky trick (e.g. maybe finding some elementary fibration or something?) but it seems hard.

Comment: Thanks very much! I’ve edit my question and added some of my ideas. I think it works but not sure.

Comment: Something doesn't sound right. Sure, if $k'$ is a finite separable extension of $k$ then $\mathbb{A}^n_{k'}$ is a connected finite étale cover of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$. How do you know that's all of them? I am unable to conceive of a proof that works only when $k$ is not algebraically closed – surely the same proof would just show that $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ has no non-trivial connected finite étale covers when $k$ is algebraically closed?

Comment: Once $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}_{k^s}^n)=0$, we know $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}_k^n)\cong Gal(k^s/k)$. I think since there is an equivalence of categories between finite etale coverings of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ and finite set with a continuous $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}_k^n)$ action. Those covering obtained by disjoint union of base change form a subcategory which is equivalent to the big category of finite etale coverings?

Comment: @AlexYoucis What about the following argument: $\ell$-adic local systems should correspond to finite projective modules with integrable connection (Riemann-Hilbert, but I don't have a proper reference in the $\ell$-adic case). It follows from Quillen-Suslin that finite projective modules over $k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ are free, and then by the Poincaré lemma, integrable connections are also trivial.

Comment: @Yai0Phah Which Poincare lemma? I'm not sure, but I think that secretly that is also using analytification. A simple argument was suggested to me by my friend Piotr Achinger--I'll post it here eventually once I get time. I think there's also probably a characteristic classes argument that one can make which formally appears similar to the degree argument that tried to make for the n=1 case.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I was mistaken, for the following two reasons: 1. There seems no comparison between étale sheaves and modules with connection when the scheme in question is not proper; 2. Even on a vector bundle of rank $1$ over $\mathbb C[X]$ (generated by $v$), a connection (automatically integrable) is not necessarily algebraically trivial: $\mathbb C[t]v$ with $\mathrm d_tv=-v$, then $d_t(fv)=f'v+f\mathrm d_tv=(f'-f)v$ of which the horizontal section is transcendental therefore the connection is not algebraically trivial.